# Cannot get CSS carousel slides img or text within to be clickable links

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink, carousel

I have a CSS carousel that is working great thanks to a great coder on here, but as I am finishing up my project, I cannot make the images or text clickable in the slides. I have wrapped  around the img, I have connect it to the text, and I cannot click anything, it just slides on its merry way. Below is the code:

```
.colorDissolve {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 287px;
    height: 430px;
    background: #000000;
}
.colorDissolve .item {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation: colorDissolve 24s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: colorDissolve 24s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: colorDissolve 24s linear infinite;
    animation: colorDissolve 24s linear infinite;
}
.colorDissolve .item:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s;
}
.colorDissolve .item:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
    animation-delay: 12s;
}
.colorDissolve .item:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
    animation-delay: 18s;
}
.stars{
    height: 220px;
    background-color: rgba(11, 11, 44, 0.6);
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 120px;
    margin-top: -135px;
    top:200px;
    bottom:200px;
    right:100px;
    left:220px;
    bottom: 143px;
    color: #8df4fb;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.space{
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    bottom:100px;
    left:390px;
    color:#c30;
    font-size:.9em;
    padding:0.5em;
    position:absolute;
    right:10px;
    left:10px;
    text-align:right;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

@-webkit-keyframes colorDissolve {
    0%, 25%, 100% { opacity: 0; }
    4.17%, 20.84% { opacity: 1;}
}
@-moz-keyframes colorDissolve {
    0%, 25%, 100% { opacity: 0; }
    4.17%, 20.84% { opacity: 1;}
}
@-ms-keyframes colorDissolve {
    0%, 25%, 100% { opacity: 0; }
    4.17%, 20.84% { opacity: 1;}
}
@keyframes colorDissolve {
    0%, 25%, 100% { opacity: 0; }
    4.17%, 20.84% { opacity: 1;}
}

<div class="carousel colorDissolve">
    <div class="item">
        <a href="star.html"> 
            <img  src="images/stars.gif" />
        </a>
        <span class="stars"> 
            <h2>Science</h2>
            <p>TEXT</p>
            <h2>The new Style of Space</h2>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="space.html"> 
            <img  src="images/galaxy.gif" />
        </a>
        <span class="space"> 
            <h2>Science</h2>
            <p>TEXT</p>
            <h2>The new Style of Space</h2>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="moon.html"> 
            <img  src="images/moons.gif" />
        </a>
        <span class="space"> 
            <h2>Science</h2>
            <p>TEXT</p>
            <h2>The new Style of Space</h2>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="nebula.html"> 
            <img  src="images/nebulae.gif" />
        </a>
        <span class="space"> 
            <h2>Science</h2>
            <p>TEXT</p>
            <h2>The new Style of Space</h2>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I also have put the link code by the text, around the headers, and there is no link option. I tried the z-index, and it still does not work, and I do not think it should go higher than my nav links, right? Are maybe my nav links somehow messing up my img links? I am not sure what I am missing, I have put the  in the span sections as well, but I cannot get it to work. I also have links to facebook and twitter, but they do not interfere with anything. I am just a bit stuck here. I just cannot solve this problem.

EDIT: Ok, so I now have the links working for text, what I was able to do was use the z-index to put the linked text on top of the div layer and I can now click on those links as they are present. I obviously made the z-index ratio higher than the links in the footer, and it works great. The only issue I still have is getting the whole slide itself or just the picture itself to link or be clickable in its own right, as it pulls from another div layer, basically using my ul a attribute when I hover over the picture, which is not what I want it to do.

Comment: Why is the first html tag character `<` missing from all your div class="item"?

Answer (score 0):

That's weird, for me it works correctly (only you forgot the first `<` tags for your item divs)

- If you want a clickable entire div => change `<div class="item">` to `<a class="item">`
- If you want a clickable image inside div => wrap a tags around the img
- If you want a clickable text inside div => wrap a tags around `<span class="space">`

If it doesn't work, you've probably made a typing mistake, because in this test:
http://jsbin.com/apuwal/2/edit , wherever I wrap the anchor tags, it works.

**EDIT:** Ah I got you now. I re-tested the code with a function alerting the href of a link when clicking on it. After some searching, it turned out, you have to scrap the `position: absolute;` from your classes `.space` (twice!) & `.item`. http://jsbin.com/apuwal/7/edit

This is because absolute positioning ignores the presence of other elements, and so your elements will all stack up at the same position and only one link will be clickable. If you wish to keep the position of your items absolute, you will either have to:

- set different margins for your elements so they don't overlap
- Use keyframes (dunno if this is possible, never tried) to change the z-index of the item with opacity > 0.5 or so
- Set your items to `display: none;` when they finish fading out. (through Javascript/ jQuery)
- Give the hidden elements a different margin when they fade out.

I know CSS sliders/faders are pretty sophisticated now, but the way I see it right now, the easiest solution would still be javascript

Comment: thanks for the response. The issue with the <a href="star.html"> you have in the test is that it does the same link for every slide. Each slide is clickable to the same link, even though the <a href="star.html"> tag is wrapped around only one span. When I wrap around the link tag say over the div, it pulls from another link property from my facebook structure, which is odd.

Comment: I will post that code as well: ul,
 li {

  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  
 }
 ul {
  text-align: center;
 }
 ul.social_pop li,
 ul.menu_b li{
  display: inline;
 }
 a:hover,
 a:focus {
  z-index: 20 
 }
 a img {
  border: none;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s; 
 }
 ul.social_pop a img{
  -webkit-transform-origin: top; 
  -moz-transform-origin: top; 
 }
 a:hover img,
 a:focus img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.5);

 }